# What lemma is $\left|\sum^p_{m=1}{e^{2\pi ixm}}\right|\le{\mathrm{min}\left(P,\frac{1}{2\left|\left|x\right|\right|}\right)\ }$?

Tags: number-theory

Lemma:

> $$\left|\sum^P_{m=1}{e^{2\pi ixm}}\right|\le {\mathrm{min} \left(P,\frac{1}{2\left|\left|x\right|\right|}\right)\ }$$
>   where $\|\cdot \|:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1/2]$ is the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer.

Does anyone recognize this lemma? I'd appreciate if you could point out what it is and where it comes from.

Comment: What is $P$ ???

Comment: There are essentially two inequalities to prove. Given some mild conditions on the variables one inequality is obvious, the other is not. What have you found yourself? Where did you come across this 'lemma'? Please provide some context, details and own research.

Comment: What is $x$?  What does $\|x\|$ mean in this context?

Comment: If $\|x\|$ is the fractional part, then for $p=1$ and $x=0.75$; ${\mathrm{min} \left(1,\frac{1}{2\left|\left|0.75\right|\right|}\right)\ }$ is about $0.66$, which is less than the LHS.

Comment: In this context $\| x\|$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer, so $\| 0.75\|=0.25$.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS can be computed as a geometric progression, giving

$$\left|\frac{e^{2\pi i xp}-1}{e^{2\pi i x}-1}\right|,$$

and after a little trigonometric simplifications,$$\left|\frac{\sin\pi xp}{\sin\pi x}\right|.$$

This is not at all bounded by $\dfrac1{2|x|}$.

Comment: To add to this answer a bit: to see that there is no hope of this bound applying, note that the LHS is periodic. In fact, whenever $x$ is an integer, the LHS is equal to $p$. So, for arbitrarily large values of $x$ the LHS equals $p$. Meanwhile, the bound $\frac{1}{2|x|}$ becomes arbitrarily small as $x$ becomes arbitrarily large. However, it does seem like if you make some kind of restriction like $|x| < 1$, then the statement would hold. Are you sure there isn't a restriction like this in the problem, OP?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins; one could think that $\|x\|$ denotes the fractional part.

Comment: That seems like it could actually be true also, although I have no idea how I would go about proving it.

Comment: This is the proof, combined with Jordan's inequality that $\sin(\pi x)\geq 2x$, valid for $0\leq\lvert x\rvert\leq 1/2$, given that $\| x\|\in[0,\tfrac{1}{2}]$ denotes the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer.